# How do i get the total amount of objects with a bool value of true or false in ListView?

Tags: python, django, listview

Trying to get the total count of objects with a bool value of true to display on the template

Here's what I have so far

models.py

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    MARK_AS = ((True, 'Open'), (False, 'Closed'))
   
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    mark_as = models.BooleanField(choices=MARK_AS, default=True)
```

views.py

```
class IssueListView(ListView):
    model = Issue
    template_name = 'issues/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'issues'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5
    
    def total():
        open_issues = Issue.objects.filter(mark_as=True).count()
        closed_issues = Issue.objects.filter(mark_as=False).count()
        context = { 
                'open_issues': open_issues,
                'closed_issues': closed_issues}
        return context
```

template

```
<ul class="topics__list">
        <li>
            <a href="" class="active">All <span>{{ page_obj.paginator.count }}</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Open<span>{{issues.open_issues}}</span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Closed<span>{{issues.closed_issues}}</span></a>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

It doesn't work, where do i go from here?

Comment: Where is `def total()` called from? That method is not one that the `ListView` uses by default - so it's never going to be used unless you call it yourself. If you want to add stuff to the context, override [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context-1).

Answer (score 0):

The context value for the `issues` you're passing in are `issues.open_issues` and `issues.closed_issues` for the template. Try changing your template to match the dictionary keys that you're passing in.

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work. I've edited the original post to reflect that.  Thanks for the suggestion tho